# Why can an anonymous Action invoke in one line in C# but not VB?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In C#

```c#
(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Hello"))).BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

In VB the translated code doesn't compile

```vb
(New Action(Sub() MessageBox.Show("Hello"))).BeginInvoke(nothing, nothing)
```

But in VB I can set the result of BeginInvoke to implicit variable `a` and it will run (thanks @Ric for this suggestion in another post)

```vb
Dim a = (New Action(Sub() MessageBox.Show("Hello"))).BeginInvoke(Nothing, Nothing)
```

But now I want to know why VB requires something to be set on the left hand side in this case, where C# does not.

Comment: If you put `Call` infront of it (without doing `dim a = `), does it compile?

Comment: If you're going to report a compilation error, you should *always* show what that error is.

Comment: Note that you don't need anything quite as complicated as this to show the problem. `New Random().Next()` gives an error too.

Comment: @John Skeet It simply says "Syntax error." Nothing more than that. The leading parenthesis is underlined by the compiler.

Comment: @DanV The point Jon Skeet was making was that you should always *include* the error in your question. =)

Comment: @DanV: All of that would have been worth including in the question to start with.

Comment: It's so us C# types can feel a little more superior. :D

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Fortunately, I got some great answers below despite leaving out the compilation error and providing a complicated example.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I came from a couple years of C# before working with VB. It felt like a downgrade at first but I got used to the imo much easier to read lambdas :)

Comment: Came from Delphi, but I had a two year experience with VB6. That put me off anything starting with VB for the next several lifetimes. Also until 3.5 got launched VB.net was well behind C# functionality wise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VB.NET simply requires an identifier. You can't invoke a sub or other member directly like that. You can, however, use `Call` instead.

> You typically use the Call keyword when the called expression doesn’t start with an identifier. Use of the Call keyword for other uses isn’t recommended.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Call (New Action(Sub() MessageBox.Show("Hello"))).BeginInvoke(nothing, nothing)
```

Comment: This works. It just reminds me too much of my VB6 days. Thanks :)

Comment: @DanV Yeah, it's definitely one of the legacy bits left over from VB6. I've run into it myself. I recently went into a VB.NET project and had to face this hurdle, like so many others, as a non-VB.NET developer ;)

Answer (score 2):

VB doesn't allow invoking member calls directly on an instantiation.
Use:

```
CType(New Action(Function() MessageBox.Show("Hello")), Action).BeginInvoke(Nothing, Nothing)
```

Comment: This works. Is there a reason why we can't invoke member calls directly on instantiation in VB while C# allows it?